# Class org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.localsessionfactorybean not found despite being up to date

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-bean

I've circled some answers around the web, but many say to just update the pom file's dependencies, which I've done. Up to this point, I don't know what to do anymore. Here is the pom's details and dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.10.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and here is just the part of my servlet-context that uses the "missing" class:

```
<beans:bean id="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.localsessionfactorybean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>net.quarksoft.springmvc.model.Users</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
            </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

I've seen and found that the spring-orm from 4.1.3 and ahead support hibernate 5, both of which are in the pom as the spring-orm version 5.1.2 and as hibernate-core 5.4.2. In my dependencies folder there are no clashing versions of the same class, so that's not the problem. Any and all help is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the class name should be case sensitive which means it should be :

```xml
    <beans:bean id="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory"
                    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

Comment: I am so blind, I swear to god. Thanks a lot for clearing that up, though!